# T-SQL Return text in CASE with numeric check

Tags: sql-server, case

When I do this :

```
select 
    'Result' = 
    case 
        when my_table.value > 0 
        then 'Correct'
        else 'Not Correct'
    end
from table as my_table
```

It always returns something like this:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Correct' to data type int.
```

How can I achieve this ? Isn't it possible to return a text value after a numeric check in a CASE statement ?

thanks !

k.

Comment: what's te type and content of `my_table.value`?

Comment: You are mixing integers with varchar outputs. 'Correct' and 'Not Correct' are varchar. STRINGS. 0 is an integer. So when some of your stuff shows an integer, and others show a string FOR THE SAME COLUMN, then you will get that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing technically wrong with your syntax, your query can be fairly easily replicated with:

```
SELECT 'Result' = CASE WHEN my_table.value > 0  THEN 'Correct'
                        ELSE 'Not Correct'
                    END
FROM (VALUES (1), (0)) My_Table (Value);
```

which works fine. You can do whatever checks you like as long as all the return types are the same, or implicitly convertable to the data type with the highest precedence, e.g. This still works:

```
SELECT 'Result' = CASE WHEN my_table.value > 0  THEN 1 -- INTEGER/INTEGER
                        WHEN 'Test' = 'Test2' THEN 0.5 -- TEXT/DECIMAL 
                        ELSE '0' --/TEXT
                    END
FROM (VALUES (1), (0)) My_Table (Value);
```

The comment shows the `Expresson Type/Return Type`. I suspect that the actual problem comes from either a UNION that you have not posted, or further expressions in the case expression that you have not posted.

For example, although the top part runs fine on its own above, running this:

```
SELECT 'Result' = CASE WHEN my_table.value > 0  THEN 'Correct'
                        ELSE 'Not Correct'
                    END
FROM (VALUES (1), (0)) My_Table (Value)
UNION ALL
SELECT 1;
```

Will give the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Correct' to data type int.

As an aside, I'd suggest getting away from using literals for column aliases though, for one it is on the deprecation list, but IMO it can also get confusing, especially, as in this case, when combined with actual string literals.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear. I learned something new today.
The case statement is indeed not fully showed here, and the problem must come from there.

Comment: you are spot on with UNION being a potential cause of this error. I was scratching my head for ages until I realised it was only occurring in one of the queries I had unioned together

Answer (score 0):

It fails because my_table.Value is of different datatype. try this

```
;with t 
As
(
select 
    'Result' = 
    case 
        when my_table.value > 0 
        then 1
        else 0
    end
from table as my_table
)

select CASE WHEN t.Result = 1 then 'CORRECT' ELSE 'WRONG' END FROM t
```

OR

```
;with t 
As

(
SELECT CASE WHEN my_table.value > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END as Result FROM dbo.my_table
)
    select CASE WHEN t.Result = 1 then 'CORRECT' ELSE 'WRONG' END FROM t
```

Comment: I downvoted because the answer is not correct, the types in the expression are completely independent of the types in the return type. The query posted works fine. Furthermore if this were true, you would have exactly the same issue in the answer posted in this expression `CASE WHEN t.Result = 1 then 'CORRECT' ELSE 'WRONG' END`